# Explain the method of pow function of math.h in C

Tags: c

I am learned about C# but I want to learn C and then C++ for OOP. now I am working with library math.h and function of pow(x,y) in C.
I am writing a program with this code:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhZ8h.png)
I get something very strange. It's result of that:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/En3Cg.png)

My problem is about pow. what does it do?
Is it possible to explain for me why this things showed? I can't understand.
Thanks for help and I'm sorry for my English too.

Comment: Please don't put printscreens of errors, put the actual message you have in the question, as text. Also, learning C++ for OOP when you're already learning C#, really?

Comment: `1/4 = 0` since since `1` and `4` are both integer literals.  When you divide them, you get an integer as the result with the remainder lopped off.

Comment: I update it. "learning C++ for OOP when you're already learning C#" because C++ need low memory and I have to use it in some programs.

Comment: In addition the issue that integer division results in integers, test cases #5 and #6 aren't actually testing what you think (you're calling `printf()` with the result of some other `pow()` expression, *not* with `number`), and the last test case (`pow(3200000, 0.20)`) did produce the correct result.

Comment: And adding on to what AntonH said, please don't post screenshots of the code you'r asking about either.  Copy and paste.

Comment: Oh. Ok I'm understanding.

Comment: I delete it because it's my mistake. Thanks.

Comment: Post code here, as text, to add clarity to the question.

Comment: It works properly now. It's my mistake. sorry. just overlock my fault.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue with your code is that you must understand how operations are handled for the several native types C can handle.

The **divide** operation  (/) will return an integer if both operators are integers.

That is:

```
1 / 4 == 0
```

and not **0.25** as it seems you're expecting.

Therefore, in line:

```
number = pow(160000, 1 / 4);
```

what you're actually executing is:

```
number = pow(160000, 0);
```

and we know that any base raised to the **0** power is equals to **1**

Comment: I know that.. my probelm is about pow!!

Comment: Your comment in line // We know that 1/4 = 0.25 does not correspond with that understanding

Comment: `1 / 4 != 1` actually :) I guess you meant to say `0`.

Comment: Yes! Sorry about that! Corrected the result. Thanks @FreeNickname

Answer (score 1):

The compiler treats '1/4' as integer division.

What this means is that it first does the division which evaluates to 0.25 then casts it to an integer (discard the decimal) leaving you with 0. And any number raised to the power of 0 is 1.

Adding the decimal points after the 1 and 4 lets the compiler know that you want the result of your division to be a double so it keeps the result as 0.25.

Here's some example code:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <math.h>

int main()
{
    double number = 1/4;
    printf("Integer Division: %f\n", number); //prints 0

    number = 1.0/4.0;
    printf("Double Division: %f\n", number); //prints 0.25

    return 0;
}
```